# Use hidden states instead of outputs in LSTMs of keras

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I want to use an implementation of an attention mechanism by [Yang et al.](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N16-1174). I found a working implementation of a custom layer that uses this attention machanism [here](https://gist.github.com/cbaziotis/7ef97ccf71cbc14366835198c09809d2). Instead of using the output values of my LSTM:

```
my_lstm = LSTM(128, input_shape=(a, b), return_sequences=True)
my_lstm = AttentionWithContext()(my_lstm)
out = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(my_lstm)
```

I would like to use the hidden states of the LSTM:

```
my_lstm = LSTM(128, input_shape=(a, b), return_state=True)
my_lstm = AttentionWithContext()(my_lstm)
out = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(my_lstm)
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

I tried it in combination with return_sequences but everything I've tried failed so far. How can I modify the returning tensors in order to use it like the returned output sequences?

Thanks!

Comment: `return_state=True` only returns the last hidden state, not all the hidden states. So even if you edited AttentionWithContext to work with the list of tensors you get when `return_state=True` I don't think it would be what you want.

Comment: @NicoleWhite Ok, that'd be a problem. I don't see the reason why it only returns the last hidden state, but so be it. I have to wonder though: In most of the papers they talk about the hidden state. Is this really what they mean or do they just use the wrong terminology? I don't see a reason to use the hidden state instead of the output state, but I want to use their method correctly.

Comment: What are you referring to when you say output state?

Comment: @NicoleWhite I'm using the terminology from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory#Traditional_LSTM) for the traditional LSTM. In that case we have the cell state vector and an output vector. And I would have called the cell state vector a hidden state but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think your confusion possibly stems from the Keras documentation being a little unclear.

```
return_sequences: Boolean. Whether to return the last output in the output sequence, or the full sequence.
return_state: Boolean. Whether to return the last state in addition to the output.
```

The docs on `return_state` are especially confusing because they imply that the hidden states are different from the outputs, but they are one in the same. For LSTMs this gets a little murky because in addition to the hidden (output) states, there is the cell state. We can confirm this by looking at the LSTM step function in the Keras code:

```
class LSTM(Recurrent):
    def step(...):
        ...
        return h, [h, c]
```

The return type of this step function is `output, states`. So we can see that the hidden state `h` is actually the output, and for the states we get both the hidden state `h` and the cell state `c`. This is why you see the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory#Traditional_LSTM) you linked using the terms "hidden" and "output" interchangeably.

Looking at the paper you linked a little closer, it seems to me your original implementation is what you want.

```
my_lstm = LSTM(128, input_shape=(a, b), return_sequences=True)
my_lstm = AttentionWithContext()(my_lstm)
out = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(my_lstm)
```

This will pass the hidden state at each timestep to your attention layer. The only scenario where you are out of luck is the one where you actually want to pass the cell state from each timestep to your attention layer (which is what I thought initially), but I do not think this is what you want. The paper you linked actually uses a GRU layer, which has no concept of a cell state, and whose step function also returns the hidden state as the output.

```
class GRU(Recurrent):
    def step(...):
        ...
        return h, [h]
```

So the paper is almost certainly referring to the hidden states (aka outputs) and not the cell states.

Comment: I was just going through the paper again and also noticed they use GRUs. I wasn't familiar enough with them to know they do not use a cell state. Since I thought they mean the cell state of the GRU in the paper, I actually wanted to get the cell state of the LSTM for my attention layer. Now I know there is no cell state in GRUs and Yang et al. can only mean the output (or hidden vector). Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: @Nicole White,  Thanks for the explanation. In your solution, is there any way to just write (store the hidden states (i.e., outputs), into a file instead of feeding them into an attention layer? Thanks for any idea on this!

Comment: Could you please provide a link to github line for your code snippets?

Comment: A link to a line in a codebase is likely to become obsolete as the project is updated. I think it would be better if someone just searched for the GRU class in the codebase.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add one point to the Nicole's answer -

If we use combination of `return_state = True` and `return_sequences = True` in LSTM then the first [h] will return the hidden state aka output at each time step (vector) whereas 2nd [h] will return hidden state at last time step (scalar).

Comment: Source: https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/ :D